# OO PHP, class function variable

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
include("classes/list.php");
    $start = new listPage();
    $start->category=3;
```

And the list.php:

```
class listPage
{
  public $category;

  function __construct()
  {
    echo $this->category;
  }
}
```

And it's not working. The $start->category part doesn't set the value of the variable. Any idea?

Comment: This `echo $this->category;` fires as soon as the code gets to this `$start = new listPage();` line. Hence, the value isn't set yet, i.e.; the constructor code is executed the moment an object of the class is created

Comment: I changed __construct to a new function and called it after setting the category ($start->category=3; $start->echoit;), but the same..

Comment: You could also pass in a default value to the construct function like `$start = new listPage(3);` and change `__construct` to something like `function __construct($defaultCat){ $this->category = $defaultCat; ...rest of construct function`

Comment: @Vivek why did you think it was me?

Comment: @Vivek Well, it wasn't me. But at first it was wrong by just setting the value to 3 always. So that is probably why downvote.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I was in the edit mode that time. neways my bad luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code will go like this:-

### List.php

```
class listPage
{
  public $category;

  function __construct()
  {
    $this->category = '';
  }
  function setCategory($value)
  {
     $this->category=$value;
     echo $this->category;
  }
}
```

### Controller.php

```
$start = new listPage();
$start->setCategory(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__construct` is called as soon as you do `new listPage()` so if you pass a value to this then it will be sent to the `__construct` method.

```
include("classes/list.php");
$start = new listPage(3); // this will be passed to the constructor
echo $start->getCategory; // echo the category here or maybe use it to construct a URL
```

And the list.php:

```
class listPage
{
  public $category;

  public function __construct($cat)
  {
    $this->category = $cat; // the constructor will set the category sent to it
  }

  public function getCategory()
  {
      return $this->category; // just return the category instead of echoing it so that you can do whatever you want with it in your code where its being fetched.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that __construct() is called before category is set to 3. You must put the echo in a separate method and call it after setting $start->category.

Answer (score 0):

The construct only happens when you first create the object with your `$start = new listPage();`

What you need to do is create a method that will take your parameters like this:

```
class listPage
{
  public $category;

  function echoCategory($category){
      $this->category = $category;
      echo $this->category;
  }

}
```

and then you'd call it like so:

```
include("classes/list.php");
$start = new listPage();
$start->echoCategory(3);
```

Comment: @JonathanKuhn actually this will work just fine, there's no longer a constructor as there's nothing that needs to be initiated. if anything we can have the $this->category = 0, but that still wouldn't need a constructor.

Comment: I wrote this:

class listPage{
public $category;
 
 public function setValue($withit)
 {
  $this->category=$withit;
  echo $this->category;
                $this->writeit();
 }

protected function writeit()
{
echo $this->category;
}
}

I could set the value to 3 and its working in the setValue function, but the writeit function echo nothing

Comment: Yea, I read it wrong. I was thinking echoCategory was a constructor function that you were setting the value in.

Answer (score 0):

In OOP the construct method is used to, well, *construct* your object, so you can initialize parameters in it, eg:

```
class myClass {
  public $myValue;
  function __construct() {
    $myValue = "someValue";
  }
}
```

When instantiate a class the constructor method is fired automatically, that is the value is assigned (or in your case is echoed).

You should change your class definition, either you construct your value on instanciation or you create setter methods, the first would be somehting like

```
class listPage {
  public $category;

  function __construct($someVal) {
    $this->category = $someVal;
  }
}

$clazz = new listPage("someVal");
echo $clazz->category;
```

Or you create a setter method:

```
class listPage {
  public $category;

  function __construct() { }

  function setCategory($cat) { $this->category = $cat; }
}

$clazz = new listPage();
$clazz->setCategory("someVal");
echo $clazz->category;
```

To extend the discussion further you could also make `$category` private and use setters and getters, you would need then to add a method to the last example:

```
function getCategory() { return $this->category; }
```

This is useful if you want to control access to the variable.

Comment: Yea it works, but if i create an other function in the class like protected function writeit() { echo $this->category; } it write nothing :(

Comment: You have to set the variable before calling the getter (or in your case `writeit`), if you don't set the variable first it can never print something, if you meant that it was not storing the variable it's because it must be `$this->category = $someVal;` and not echo.